# SaltStack: $HOME of users which does not exist yet

Tags: salt-stack, user-management, home-directory

I create a user `foo` on a minion.  The minion evalutes `/etc/default/useradd`. This means the salt master does not know whether the new $HOME will be `/home/foo` or in our case `/localhome/foo`.

How can I get the $HOME of user `foo` as jinia variable?

I need it in a systemd service file.

I would like to avoid custom pillar data, since this is redundant. Is there a way to get it via grains?

Does it work during boostrapping? First the user `foo` needs to be created, then the systemd file can be created by looking up the $HOME of `foo`...

This would work if the user does already exist:

```
{{ salt['user.info'](user).get('home') }}/foo:
  file.recurse:
    - source:    salt://conf/common/foo
```

Related issue: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/7883

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer this question:

> Is there a way to get it via grains?

1) add file '_grains/homeprefix.py' under the `file_roots` specified by the master config file, the content of which is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os.path import dirname, expanduser

def gethomeprefix():
  # initialize a grains dictionary
  grains = {}
  # Some code for logic that sets grains like
  grains['homeprefix'] = dirname(expanduser("~"))
  return grains
```

2) run sync cmd on master to sync grains info to minion :

```
salt '*' saltutil.sync_grains
```

3) run grains.get on master to test :

```
salt '*' grains.get homeprefix
```